# Python: creating an idempotent initializer

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the correct way to create an idempotent initializer in python? By idempotent I mean that if object `x` is an instance of class `A` then `A(x) is x` (like in regex patterns, frozensets, strings, and tuples). I can think of three solutions:

1. override `new`

   ```
   class A:
     def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
       if not kwargs and len(args) == 1 and isinstance(args[0],cls):
          return args[0]
       return super().__new__(*args, **kwargs)
     def __init__(*args, **kwargs):
       # check that init isn't called on the same object twice
       if not kwargs and len(args) == 1 and isinstance(args[0],cls):
          return
       ... # actual initialization goes here
   ```
2. hide the actual class behind an initialization function

   ```
   class A:
       ...
   def a(*args, **kwargs):
       if not kwargs and len(args) == 1 and isinstance(args[0], A):
           return args[0]
       return A(*args, **kwargs)
   ```
3. make a metaclass

   ```
   class Meta(type):
       def __call__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
           if not kwargs and len(args) == 1 and isinstance(args[0], cls):
               return args[0]
           return super().__call__(*args, **kwargs)
   class A(metaclass = Meta):
       ...
   ```

   All these solutions seem hack-ish to me, and each with significent drawbacks. What is the cannonical way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The canonical way is having `__new__` return the object itself. That's exactly what `frozenset`, strings and tuples do, albeit in C code.

For example, `frozenset.__new__` is [`setobject.c` `frozenset_new()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/260ec2c36abd73bac51489108409160427979ede/Objects/setobject.c#L1093-L1123) which uses:

```
/* frozenset(f) is idempotent */
if (PyFrozenSet_CheckExact(iterable)) {
    Py_INCREF(iterable);
    return iterable;
}
```

Take into account that these are **immutable** types, so they do not define an `__init__` method (or the C equivalent). That's important, because returning an object that's an instance of the current class (or a subclass) from `__new__`, will automatically trigger `__init__` being called if defined. You would not want to have your objects re-initialised here!

So the correct implementation would put *everything in `__new__`*:

```
class A:
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if not kwargs and len(args) == 1 and isinstance(args[0], cls):
            # A(instance_of_A) is idempotent
            return args[0]

        instance = super().__new__(*args, **kwargs)
        # actual initialization goes here
        return instance

    # **NO** __init__ method for 'immutable' objects
```

Comment: Fair points and great answer, thanks. Though I would remark that I did ensure that the __init__ method does not affect objects returned in this way.

Comment: @bentheiii: I know, but that's just a work-around for using `__init__` on what is supposed to be an immutable object, really.